# Wireshark: how to export a usb/midi/sysex message from several frames

Tags: wireshark

I captured some usb/midi/sysex outbound frames. I would like to export a merge of "reassembled message" from all these frames as a single hexdump. I marked the interesting packets/frames (there is a lot more of them than seen in the screenshot). Yet everything related to export in the File menu is grayed out, including submenus of "Packet Dissections" and "Objects":
[image]